# How to make a wrapper function for Navigate in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router` v5 and I want to upgrade to v6. There is a problem: I have many components and use `useHistory` inside them but I don't want to change them one by one to `useNavigate` instead of that I want to write a helper function for `navigate`(`history`) in `react-router` v6 and then use that helper(wrapper) function.

Question is: How to write a helper function for `useNavigate` in `react-router` v6?

Comment: What's wrong with completely replacing all `useHistory` hooks with the `useNavigate` hook? If upgrading from RRDv5 to v6 you'll need to do this anyway. What have you tried already? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: one reason is if one day we need to upgrade again just change that helper file and there is no need to change all of the project's files.

Comment: So you want to create a custom hook that uses `useHistory`, then upgrade from v5 to v6, and keep using the custom hook? There isn't a 1-1 mapping of the RRDv5 `history` object to the RRDv6 `navigate` function. How much of the RRDv5 `history` object behavior do you want/need to retain?

Comment: yes, almost and for v6 I can use useNavigate instead of useHistory in it, and maybe for the next version I use another thing if I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to provide a custom navigation utility then you'll likely want to create a custom React hook that "wraps" one of the hooks provided from `react-router` and return the functions you need. Unfortunately `react-router@6` doesn't directly expose out the `history` object, and there isn't a 1-to-1 relationship between the `history` object and the `navigate` function. You can cover most common use cases though. I suggest adhering to a "common API" that fits your needs.

### RRDv5 Example

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

const useMyNavigation = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const push = React.useCallback((to, state) => history.push(to, state), []);

  const replace = React.useCallback((to, state) => history.replace(to, state), []);

  const go = React.useCallback((delta) => history.go(delta), []);

  const back = React.useCallback(() => history.back(-1), []);

  const forward = React.useCallback(() => history.go(1), []);

  return {
    back
    forward,
    go,
    push,
    replace
  };
};
```

### RRDv6 Example

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

const useMyNavigation = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const push = React.useCallback((to, state) => navigate(to, { state }), []);

  const replace = React.useCallback((to, state) => navigate(to, { replace: true, state }), []);

  const go = React.useCallback((delta) => navigate(delta), []);

  const back = React.useCallback(() => navigate(-1), []);

  const forward = React.useCallback(() => navigate(1), []);

  return {
    back
    forward,
    go,
    push,
    replace
  };
};
```

### Alternative RRDv6 Example

Now, when I said that RRDv6 doesn't directly expose out the `history` object, this isn't *entirely* true. It ***does not*** directly export the `history` object, but it ***does*** export the React context holding it via the [`UNSAFE_NavigationContext`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.ts#L236) context. With this you *can* get a reference to the `navigator` function which is a `history@5` `history` object (*as opposed to the `history@4` that RRDv5 uses*). Note that this likely requires `history@5` (*the same version used by `react-router@6`*) to be listed as a project dependency. See [`history@5` Navigation](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#navigation).

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

const useMyNavigation = () => {
  const navigator = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext).navigator;

  const push = React.useCallback((to, state) => navigator.push(to, state), []);

  const replace = React.useCallback((to, state) => navigator.replace(to, state), []);

  const go = React.useCallback((delta) => navigator.go(delta), []);

  const back = React.useCallback(() => navigator.back(-1), []);

  const forward = React.useCallback(() => navigator.go(1), []);

  return {
    back
    forward,
    go,
    push,
    replace
  };
};
```